# Fast v/s conventional way of retrieving records from database

Tags: mysql, database, search, join

I've two tables:

```
story
--id
--name

article
--id
--name
```

A group of articles makes up a story. And, the user will be searching in the story table. And getting all the articles corresponding to that particular story.

I could follow two ways:

1. Insert a row in `story`table: `article_list` and store the `article.id`s separated by `,`. This way, for a particular story searched, I will have all the article ids straight away.
2. Follow the conventional method of mapping the above two tables and performing `join`.

Which would be a faster way to fetch results? Results=Getting all the articles for a particular story id. So in both the above methods, I will have to fetch the results from the `article` table.

My question is basically, which of the above methods will be faster in getting me the `article` `id`s?

Comment: The first one will be faster for this specific case, but you should use the second one nonetheless. Storing a comma-separated list of ids in a relational database, is bad by definitions. There are always exceptions, but the exceptions are rare.

Comment: Do the join. What about when you want the actual article? You would need to then do another query if you just had comma separated ids.

Comment: Which is it, getting just the ids or the whole article? If it's the whole article then the join will be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the article ids then storing as comma separated will technically be faster but is generally really not a good way to store data in a database. If you need to retrieve the whole article then using a join will be both faster and a better way to store the information.